# Calendar getTimeInMillis returns same old value after chaneing date & time

Tags: android, calendar

I am converting String date and time to `Calendar` object

```
ex: 2015-09-05 16:30:20
this examples is not working: 2016-11-17 01:27:57
```

I am doing it like this

```
public static Calendar convert_String_Time_and_Date_To_Calendar(String time_and_date){
    String TimeAndDate_array[] = time_and_date.split(" ");
    String Date_details[]=TimeAndDate_array[0].split("-");
    String Time_details[]=TimeAndDate_array[1].split(":");

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,Integer.parseInt(Date_details[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,Integer.parseInt(Date_details[1]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,Integer.parseInt(Date_details[2]));

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,Integer.parseInt(Time_details[0]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,Integer.parseInt(Time_details[1]));
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,Integer.parseInt(Time_details[2]));

    calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EET"));


    return calendar;

}
```

and I am calling the method like this for ex:

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar DandT = convert_String_Time_and_Date_To_Calendar("2015-09-05 16:30:20");
if(DandT.getTimeInMillis() < today.getTimeInMillis() ){
   //do something
}else if(DandT.getTimeInMillis() == today.getTimeInMillis() ){
  //do something
}
```

the problem is the `DandT` object is still having current day time in millis, 
Actually while debugging I found that the at the method's return statement, the `calendar` object timeInMillis is the current time in mills even after calling `set()` although I checked the `calendar` object fields and found them changed !
So What is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The month should be zero based :

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,Integer.parseInt(Date_details[1]) - 1);
```

You can also make the code shorter :

```
public static Calendar convert_String_Time_and_Date_To_Calendar(String time_and_date){
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-mm-dd hh:mm");
    Date date = sdf.parse(time_and_date, 0);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(date.getTime());
    return cal;
}
```

Comment: it worked after changing the SimpleDateFormat pattern to `"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm"`. But I still do not know why my method does not work, every thing seems correct to me !

Comment: Calendar.MONTH is zero - indexed, so you will have to adjust it accordingly. Also, Time_details should only be of size 2, and yet you are accessing the third element. Maybe that is causing it to fail ? Also accept my answer if it works !

Comment: no, Time_details is of size 3, hh,mm,ss ! and it does fail it just do not change the time in Millis.
Your answer is a work around not an answer to my question, bro.

Comment: The string you have provided, 16:30, will only have 2 parts when split - 16 and 30.

Comment: Oh, Sorry I missed the seconds, I was just writing an example

Comment: In your method definition, you have used convert_String_Time_and_Date_To_Calendar while in the example you have used convert_String_Time_and_Date_To_Egypt_Calendar. Assuming these to be the same methods, your code seems to be working fine - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMR2E1VklaSTM3MGc

Comment: Yes they are the same, i was just make edits but they they are the same

Comment: I can't see any changes - I think you need to use the share code button and paste the link here.

Comment: @rhai Check this edit [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMQTZFUUFwN2Y1Z1U) it seems to fail with some examples

Comment: I edited it again and checked for the > operator  and the if worked, means that the method returns a calendar with time in millis > current time.

Comment: As I said before, month is zero-based, so 11 means December, which is in the future.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128483/discussion-between-atef-hares-and-rhari).